# Assign User on WordPress Registration to a from the User selected Usergroup

Tags: wordpress

I struggle here with a problem:

I am using the Plugins WCFM - WooCommerce Frontend Manager, WCFM - WooCommerce Multivendor Marketplace and WCFM - WooCommerce Multivendor Membership to provide my users a platform to sell E-Books.

I also use the plugin Learndash so my users can upload and sell their courses.

Now here comes the problem i want the user to choose on register either he wants sell books or courses or he want to buy books and courses.(Vendor or Customer)

Regarding this selection i want to add the user on register to the customers group so he can buy.

Or assign him to the groups Vendor from WCFM AND Instructor from Learndash so he has access to these tools.

Is there some known plugin out what can fulfill these requirements?

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Research on WordPress plugin database, research on Chat GPT.

I was expecting that other people also have this problem and there should be some solution out there because it is something what might be useful and suitable for many sites.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You simply need to put in 2 registration forms. WCFM has its own vendor registration form and Learndash too. Create a common page and based on what button the user selects redirect them to the respective registration form.